# Controller is imported but web.php throws Target class [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, model-view-controller, routes

**Update**:

When I use:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
```

inside **`LoginController.php`**, this error is thrown:

```
Class "App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Controller" not found
```

**Original Question**:

I've added following route to **`web.php`**:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController;

Route::post('/admin/login', [LoginController::class, 'store']);
```

but when called, it throws:

```
Target class [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController] does not exist.
```

This is the controller's location:

[image]

**`LoginController.php`**:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use App\Http\Requests\Auth\LoginRequest;


class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function store(LoginRequest $request)
    {
        $request->authenticate();
        $request->session()->regenerate();

        redirect('/admin/dashboard');
    }
}
```

Replacing the import inside **`web.php`** with:

```
[Auth\LoginController::class, 'store']
```

does not help either. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

in LoginController Class write wrong namespase:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
```

Comment: When I do that, I'm getting: `Class "App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Controller" not found
`

Comment: @ArturMüllerRomanov check your Route like this:Route::post('/admin/login', [LoginController::class, 'store']) ?

Comment: @ArturMüllerRomanov fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Your namespace inside `LoginController` should be `App\Http\Controllers\Auth`

Answer (score 0):

In **LoginController.php** you need to check the namespace for the file

It's not correct, because the file located inside **Auth** directory
so you must follow psr4 guide

name space will be
**App\Http\Controllers\Auth;** instead of
**App\Http\Controllers;**

Answer (score 0):

Your namespace used in LoginController is wrong, as your class is defined under Auth folder so it should be:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
```

Also the code snippet you have shared of web.php show's namespace declaration at the top, please remove this declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Importing it like so inside **`LoginController.php`** seems to resolve the issue (although I have no idea why):

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function store(LoginRequest $request)
    {
        $request->authenticate();
        $request->session()->regenerate();

        redirect('/admin/dashboard');
    }
}
```